# Does firefox support loading favicons when loading image pages (i.e. http://www.asdf.com/image.jpg)? If so, how?

Tags: html, firefox, favicon

Hey I'm having trouble getting my site's favicon to load in Firefox when displaying an image url.  I have the favicon in the root of the project and also referenced in the html pages.  Chrome loads it just fine.

Example:

This is an article from the new yorker:

http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/2012/12/the-view-from-space-20-stellar-photos-of-earth-in-2012.html#slide_ss_0=1

The page's favicon.ico looks good.  But when you go to the image of the earth in Firefox, there is no favicon.ico, just an empty square:

http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg

Obviously the image has no html wrapper, but it could grab the favicon from the root which i believe how Chrome handles it.

I'm in Firefox 23.0.1

Does firefox support loading favicons when loading images (i.e. http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg)? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support loading favicons when loading images because as you said, it doesn't grab it from the root and Chrome does. You have nothing to do with the problem, it's that Mozilla's programmers just didn't add the favicons from the root/command line. But maybe any day now they could add that and make every image with a favicon!

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming my suspicion.  Hopefully they'll slip stream this in soon.

Comment: It will, any other questions, ask me, I'll answer them.